# Two dropdown menus, only one displayed

Tags: php, html

I have two functions that both create a dropdown menu based on Mysqli input.

Each work fine by ifself, but when I call them both from a different page like this:

```
populerOevelserdropdown();
populerAntalreps();
```

only one is displayed (the first one - the second one is showing up in View source, though)

If I call like this, however:

```
populerOevelserdropdown();
populerOevelserdropdown();
populerAntalreps();
```

one of each is displayed correctly (the third one still showing up when I view source)

I'm sure it's got to do with a mismatch of tags (html, form etc.), but I can't seem to line them up properly...

Hope you guys can help - below are the two functions:

```
require_once 'forbindtilDB.php';

function populerOevelserdropdown()
{
    global $mysqliOOP;
    $stmt = $mysqliOOP->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT primaer FROM oevelser ORDER BY primaer ASC");

   ?>
   <html>
<body>
<form>
    <select multiple> 
    <option value="0">Vælg ønskede øvelse(r)</option>
        <?php
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($primaereMuskelgruppe);
            while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
        ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $primaereMuskelgruppe;?>" >
                <?php echo $primaereMuskelgruppe;
                ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }  
            $stmt->close(); 
}
function populerAntalreps()
{
    global $mysqliOOP;
    $stmt = $mysqliOOP->prepare("SELECT antalreps FROM antalreps ORDER BY antalreps ASC");

   ?>
   <html>
<body>
<form>
    <select> 
    <option value="0">Vælg ønskede antal gentagelser</option>
        <?php
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($antalreps);
            while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
        ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $antalreps;?>" >
                <?php echo $antalreps;
                ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }  
            $stmt->close(); 
}
```

Comment: You cannot print html, body twice. Think about a way to it only one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing `select` box properly. Even you are using `<html> <body> <form>` tags which is not closed. change you code like this

```
<?php
    function populerOevelserdropdown()
    {
        global $mysqliOOP;
        $stmt = $mysqliOOP->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT primaer FROM oevelser ORDER BY primaer ASC");

       ?>

    <select multiple> 
    <option value="0">Vælg ønskede øvelse(r)</option>
        <?php
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($primaereMuskelgruppe);
            while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
        ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $primaereMuskelgruppe;?>" >
                <?php echo $primaereMuskelgruppe;
                ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }  
            $stmt->close();
            ?>              
    </select>
<?php       
}

function populerAntalreps()
{
    global $mysqliOOP;
    $stmt = $mysqliOOP->prepare("SELECT antalreps FROM antalreps ORDER BY antalreps ASC");

   ?>
    <select> 
    <option value="0">Vælg ønskede antal gentagelser</option>
        <?php
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($antalreps);
            while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
        ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $antalreps;?>" >
                <?php echo $antalreps;
                ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }  
            $stmt->close();
        ?>      
    </select>       
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks Ram - and you managed to get rid of all the (currently pesky) html :)

Answer (score 0):

You should extract html and body markup from your functions...
Like this :

```
function populerOevelserdropdown()
{
    global $mysqliOOP;
    $stmt = $mysqliOOP->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT primaer FROM oevelser ORDER BY primaer ASC");

   ?>

<form>
    <select multiple> 
    <option value="0">Vælg ønskede øvelse(r)</option>
        <?php
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($primaereMuskelgruppe);
            while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
        ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $primaereMuskelgruppe;?>" >
                <?php echo $primaereMuskelgruppe;
                ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }  
            $stmt->close(); 
}
function populerAntalreps()
{
    global $mysqliOOP;
    $stmt = $mysqliOOP->prepare("SELECT antalreps FROM antalreps ORDER BY antalreps ASC");

   ?>
   <html>
<body>
<form>
    <select> 
    <option value="0">Vælg ønskede antal gentagelser</option>
        <?php
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($antalreps);
            while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
        ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $antalreps;?>" >
                <?php echo $antalreps;
                ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }  
            $stmt->close(); 
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
<?
    populerOevelserdropdown();
    populerOevelserdropdown();
    populerAntalreps();
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed closing your select box. Just `</select>` after `$stmt->close();`